# Can not get fluid background-image in css body to work

Tags: css, html, image, layout, fluid

I am trying to use a background image on my so far fully fluid web design, and have found many solutions here, but now I am stumped!  Something in my CSS is preventing my background image to display.  I am using Matthew James Taylor's multi-column liquid layouts, and whenever I try to add some new functionality everything goes haywire.  I am a newbie to web design and would appreciate your help greatly. Heres my HTML5 (hopefully valid):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-GB">
<head>
<title>Blablablah</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="description" content="Blablablah" />
<meta name="keywords" content="Blablablah" />
<meta name="robots" content="index, follow" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Blablafoo.css" media="screen" />
</head>

<body onload="parent.resizeIframe(document.body.scrollHeight)">

  <div class="colmask fullpage">
<div class="col1">
<h2>BLAAAAAAAAA BLAAAAAAAAA BLAAAAAAAAA</h2>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

And here is my CSS:

```
body {
    background-image:url(‘background.JPG’) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:0;
    width:100%;
    min-width:386px;
    min-height:100%;
    height:1px;
    font-size:90%;
}
a {
    color:#369;
}
a:hover {
    color:#fff;
    background:#369;
    text-decoration:none;
}
h1, h2, h3 {
    margin:.8em 0 .2em 0;
    padding:0;
}
p {
    margin:.4em 0 .8em 0;
    padding:0;
}
.colmask {
    position:relative;
    clear:both;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.col1 {
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    padding:0 0 1em 0;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.fullpage {
    min-height:592px;
}
.fullpage .col1 {
    width:96%;
    left:2%;
}
img {
    max-width:100%;
}
```

All files are in the same folder on my PC so its not a path thing. I have tried to put the top five lines in other parts of the CSS to no avail.

Comment: Try adding height 100%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's perfectly okay to set the background on the body element, but you have used the `background-image` definition for a list of options, that are not valid for `background-image`.
What you have specified, is a valid value for the `background` shortcut option, so both of the following variants will work:

1:

```
body {
    background: url('background.JPG') no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:0;
    width:100%;
    min-width:386px;
    min-height:100%;
    height:1px;
    font-size:90%;
}
```

2:

```
body {
    background-image: url('background.JPG');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:0;
    width:100%;
    min-width:386px;
    min-height:100%;
    height:1px;
    font-size:90%;
}
```

In addition, the quotes around your path name seem to be some kind of styled quotes, which will not work in CSS. Use simple quotes like ' or ".

Comment: I will try that, as to the quotes: that is strange, but everything here seems to work right since I have all kind of pages made with the same text editor.

Comment: Callidior, I had background without the -image before and it did not work, but since I copied Your suggestion and pasted it into my CSS so I could do a line by line comparison, It turned out that it was the quotes!!!!  Here: ' '  Somehow the code from the site I got it from uses those weird quotes.  I would have never suspected that. Foreign keyboard perhaps?!??  You have great eyes!  Thanks a million.

Comment: I used the "answer Your question" link twice now but it had no effect. Can not see the "accepted answer" anywhere, but now I have a new problem!  It works from the CSS file, but when I moved it to the html file it does not work!  It is formatted properly.

Comment: At the top of this answer, below the voting arrows, is the outline of a check icon. This is the correct link to mark this as the accepted answer ;)

Where in the HTML file did you place it?

Comment: In the body tag, like so:  <body style="background: url('chomeback.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed; -webkit-background-size: cover; -moz-background-size: cover; -o-background-size: cover; background-size: cover;">

Comment: Now my last comment won't show up unless I click on the "add/view one more comment link.

Comment: Though that is a rather "dirty" way to place such a style definition, I copied the code of your body tag and it worked for me like a charm (using Firefox). May it be a path/filename issue this time?

Comment: My mistake, (Stayed up all night). It does work, I don't know what I had wrong (time to get some sleep).  So, sie sind ein Deutscher?  Ich bin ja ein wasch echter Bayer!

Answer (score 1):

Try setting using `html` element.

```
   html { 
      background: url(https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSvctt0I--skoKQVfuVt-i4Et6vQ5ve7lXPkLy9sTElCWLKh1Ps) no-repeat center center fixed; 
      -webkit-background-size: cover;
      -moz-background-size: cover;
      -o-background-size: cover;
      background-size: cover;
    }
```

See [***demo here***](http://jsfiddle.net/wKMUG/)

**Updated:**

Another method would be using jQuery, (will work perfectly in **IE7+**)

```
$(function () {

    var theWindow = $(window),
        $bg = $("#bg"),
        aspectRatio = $bg.width() / $bg.height();

    function resizeBg() {

        if ((theWindow.width() / theWindow.height()) < aspectRatio) {
            $bg.removeClass()
                .addClass('bgheight');
        } else {
            $bg.removeClass()
                .addClass('bgwidth');
        }

    }

    theWindow.resize(function () {
        resizeBg();
    }).trigger("resize");

});
```

Then use `img` to set the background image like this:

```
<img src="http://3rdbillion.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/1b7a9c8a2df4bd4a25597f1ca0cb89f52.jpg" id="bg" alt="" />
```

You can see the [***demo here***](http://jsfiddle.net/hB2nY/)

Comment: According to what I have read that would throw off older versions of IE.  But I have tried that too, no luck.

Comment: @user3477582 Can you see the demo here. I am not able to see any issue?  http://jsfiddle.net/AQLnx/

Comment: I saw the demo, it seems to not work right either.  Mine does not show up at all!

Comment: @user3477582 another method using jquery can be used which will work perfectly in IE 7& above, see the updated post.

Comment: HOLY COW!!!!!!  It was the quotes!!  I have the same keyboard as everyone else!  Could it be that I copied the code from from a sight that was made with a foreign keyboard??  I have spent over 10 hours trying to figure it out and NOTHING that was supposed to worked!  I would have never suspected the quotes!  Ultra strange!